# Gamekit plugin WiFi functionality shutting down i phone 4

Tags: ios, wifi, gamekit, multiplayer

I am currently developing ios mobile game with blue-tooth and WiFi functionality using prime31 plugin GameKitGUIManager.cs.

But when I call GameKitBinding.showPeerPicker( true ) to enable WiFi connection in iPhone 4, 
my app shuts down.

I am confused since this method works fine when I tested in iPhone 3GS, IPad mini. 
Does anyone know why this is happening? 
The current iOS version for my iPhone 4 is 7.1.2